# Do questions about the history and discoveries of astronomy belong here?

Tags: discussion

For instance, if I were to have a question about the discovery of certain astronomical facts/ideas, is this the right place for it? Like, the who/when/how something was discovered?

Simple example: When did people realize that supernovae expel off neutrinos? / How did we discover this?

Comment: This is an excellent question! Ultimately, I think it will be up to the community. Perhaps you should test out posting such a question. You can mention in the body of the post or in a comment on it that you're not sure if it should be on topic and you can link to this meta question.

Answer (score 5):

I think history is important in astronomy. Partly because the terminology raises questions about history (like: Why are some black holes called quasars? Why the sequence OBAFGKM?) Partly because astronomy is developing quickly and is making history today, maybe on a more fundamental level than any other science. The recent remake of the TV series Cosmos had a strong emphasis on the history of astronomy.

Practically, I think that questions about the history of astronomy can get much more and better answers here than in any community about history in general. I think that the tag "history" will work here until there's enough interest to create a History of Astronomy community.